# What's a proper way of checking if a PID is running?

Tags: linux, unix, bash, process, pid

I have a `.pid` file, and I need to check if the process is running. So far I found two options

```
kill -0 `cat something.pid`
```

which prints out an error if the pid isn't running. I know this can be redirected to `/dev/null`, but it makes me think that this isn't the best solution.

The second solution would be to use `ps`, which however also prints on the STDOUT

```
ps -ef `cat something.pid`
```

Is it normal to redirect the output to `/dev/null` and just use the status code returned, or is it a sign that I'm doing something wrong and I need a different command?

Comment: Use `kill -0` as it is standard (POSIX)-compliant.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043978/how-to-check-if-a-process-id-pid-exists

Answer (score 11):

for most linux distros enumerating the /proc/{pid} is a good way to obtain information about the running processes, and usually how the userspace commands like "ps" are communicating with the kernel. So for example you can do;

```
[ -d "/proc/${kpid}" ] && echo "process exists" || echo "process not exists"
```

Edit: you should check that kpid is set, but this is more useful as it will return "not exists" for unset ${kpid}

```
[ -n "${kpid}" -a -d "/proc/${kpid}" ] && echo "process exists" || echo "process not exists"
```

Comment: @SteveMuster This would make the answer Linux-specific. There is no /proc on OSX. And I think there's no /proc on BSD.

Comment: Note with this you need to make sure `${kpid}` exists

Comment: @Wilf I edited it, so it returns "process not exists" for unset ${kpid}

Comment: Thanks - I was doing a script that checks a PID using a similar method and it didn't work till I found this was the issue :)

Answer (score 9):

As Anders noted, you should use `kill -0` for POSIX compliance.

On Linux systems, you can also check for the existence of a file in the /proc filesystem, e.g.,

```
-f /proc/$(cat something.pid)/status
```

Answer (score 4):

If this is in a script (which I assume is the case as you're worried about printing to stdout) then the following would be how you could do it:

```
if ps -p $(cat something.pid) > /dev/null 2>&1
then
    kill $(cat something.pid)
else
    # Deal with the fact that the process isn't running
    # i.e. clear up the pid file
fi
```

The `ps -p` looks for a process with the pid specified in something.pid (the `$()` syntax is a slightly newer version of the backtick. Backtick needs escaping in certain circumstances which the new form doesn't). The `2>&1` redirects stderr for that command as well.

If the `ps -p` command doesn't find the process with that PID it exits with a error > 0 and so the `else` gets executed. Otherwise the `kill` statement. You can negate the above if you want by doing:

```
if ! ps -p ...
```

Hope that answers your question. Obviously be careful and test a lot when using dangerous commands such as `kill`.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options:

- If you're writing init-script (e.g. the one to place in `/etc/init.d/`) and if you're using Debian-based distro, you'd better use `start-stop-daemon`:

  ```
  # start-stop-daemon -T -p $PIDFILE -u $USER_NAME -n $NAME
  ```

  You should get exit code 0 if it's running.
- You may use pgrep and pkill from `procps` package:

  ```
  pgrep --pidfile $PIDFILE
  ```

Answer (score 1):

If you have pid file you may use pgrep to check whether process is running:

```
    if pgrep -F something.pid; then
        echo "Running"
    else
        echo "Not running"
    fi
```

On linux you may also check for existence of `/proc/$pid` file:

```
    if [ -d "/proc/${pid}" ]; then
        echo "Running";
    else
        echo "Not running";
    fi
```

Comment: Can you feed pgrep the pid as text rather than a pid file ?

Comment: @HaydenThring, on linux you can check for existence of /proc/$pid folder:

    if [ -d "/proc/${pid}" ]; then
        echo "Running";
    else
        echo "Not running";
    fi

Answer (score -1):

if you are using java on linux

```
long pid = readPIDFile(); // write this yourself
boolean running = new File(String.format("/proc/%d", pid)).exists();
```